# Why does my desktop PC crash after upgrading or installing new memory card?

Tags: boot, memory, motherboard, bsod, desktop-computer

Before I start detailing my issue with my computer system, I would like to let you know that my system is **Compaq Presario SR1817CL Desktop PC**. I bought this computer back in 2004 or 2005. Since then, I have been using this computer without much trouble. Recently, I bought bunch of PC games to play on this system. So, I decided to beef up my memory and bought 2 of 1GB memory card. My system already had **1.5GB (1GB, 256MB, 256MB)**. Today, I pulled one of the 256MB memory card out and installed the 2 of 1GB cards. That filled up all the memory slots and increased it to **3.5GB**. My system's motherboard is **AmberineM-GL6E** and it can support upto 4GB. After that when I booted my computer system, I expected it to function like it did before without any issues. However, my computer crashed and it wouldn't even boot into any of my dual-boot windows (XP or 7). I kept getting blue screen of DEATH and the error was something to do with newly installed hardware. I thought my computer was hacked and I started the recovery process but that didn't even help. So, I decided to remove the newly installed memory cards and go back to what it was before. Viola! Now, my system is back to normal and boots normally, but I DON'T understand why. I looked in the BIOS and it listed all the memory card and their sizes totaling 3.5GB.

**UPDATE:** My system is not acting normally as I had stated. My mouse right and left click is not working right and at times my whole computer freezes...

I bought **2GB (2X1GB) PC3200 DDR 400MHz 184pin UnBuffered LOW DENSITY Desktop MEMORY**. According to the seller, these memory cards support all major brands PCs and one of them was **COMPAQ**. So, I expected them to work with my system flawlessly. Here is a direct link to the memory cards description - www[dot]newegg[dot]com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA5752R13326. Am I missing something? Do you have to stack the memory card in certain order? Is it that it can only support 1GB memory cards above 2GB memory in total? What does the memory card slots' color designation mean (Blue and Black)? I really don't know what to do next other than returning the cards back to the seller. Any help or hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Based on the sizes it honestly sounds like you had already reached the maximum amount of memory

Comment: @Ramhound How do you mean I had already reached the maximum? It can support upto 4GB and I only brought it upto 3.5GB.

Comment: The colors on the memory slots means that your motherboard supports dual channel memory. For best performance you you should install identical memory modules in the same color slots. I could explain it in details but this will not answer your actual question. To me it seems like one (or both, very unlikely) of the new memory you brought is faulty. Only install one of the new memory and boot your PC and see what happens. Do the same for the other module. Testing them individually will isolate the faulty one if there is one.

Comment: Just to expand on @Ayan comment: first, remove ALL memory sticks (you call them cards), THEN insert one of the new ones, power up PC and see what happens. If all is ok, relace it with OTHER new memory, and test it. But before make sure  memory slots are dust-free (use air can or just gently blow on them with your mouth). And yes, you should insert identical modules into same colour slots, but since you have anyway 3 different memory types it doesn't really matter. Like brain cells, memory runs as fast as the slowest one in the herd.

Comment: @AcePL thanks for explaining it in details. I was running short of space that is why I had to cut it short.

Comment: The memory could have just not worked well on that motherboard, with those timings , at that speed, at that voltage, in dual (etc) So it starts messing up the data stored in it, and the computer is unstable. Proper order of install is in the manuel, test with just one module. . This is why the motherboard manufactures have a memory compatability list, so it is more likely that the memory they tested would work without any adjustments. The memory itself did not have to be bad, although it could be. Find manuel or user info about what to use, get as close to that as possible, try again.

Comment: I checked your motherboard specs against the memory. I think you bought the exact memory you needed. I suggest doing what @AcePL said. Remove all stick and put in one at a time.

Comment: You should not boot into an OS until you confirm the hardware is working with some tool like [memtest86+](http://memtest.org/). Otherwise, you risk damaging your OS installation and you have to troubleshoot hardware and software problems at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying what was suggested in the comment section, I found out that my new Memory sticks or cards are not compatible with my old memory cards. My new memory cards by themselves in the memory slots work fine, but as soon as I put any of my old memory card (1GB or 256MB) my system crashes horribly. Somehow these new cards are different from my old cards, even though they say they should work together flawlessly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does it crash when you put new memory in one color slots and old 1 gb in other color? Skip 256MB for now. We wrote that it's not really an issue, but @PsycoGeek mentioned, the differences may be too big for the motherboard to handle. Again: DDR standard means there should be no need to pay close attention to voltage, timing and density, but manufacturers rarely stick to standards, especially big brands (they assume you will come to them for replacement/upgrade parts). I've seen it in my days of DELL DCSE quite often.